# can't read external hive table on spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive

Affects Version/s:2.3.2
Component/s:PySpark, Spark Core, Spark Shell
Labels:JSON external-tables hive spark
Environment:hdp 3.1.4

hive-hcatalog-core-3.1.0.3.1.4.0-315.jar & hive-hcatalog-core-3.1.2 both I've tried

Description
I create a external hive table with hdfs file which is formatted as json string.

I can read the data field of this hive table with the help of  org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe which is packed in hive-hcatalog-core.jar in hive shell.

But when I try to use the spark (pyspark ,spark-shell or whatever) ,I just can't read it.

It gave me a error  Table: Unable to get field from serde: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe

I've copied the jar (hive-hcatalog-core.jar) to $spark_home/jars and yarn libs and rerun ,there is no effect,even use --jars $jar_path/hive-hcatalog-core.jar.But  when I browse the webpage of spark task ,I can actually find the jar in the env list.